# Placing Data Labels Outside Pie or Doughnut Chart - Chart.js

Tags: css, angular, chart.js, pie-chart

I am working on a large scale application and it would be very helpful to place the labels on either pie charts or doughnut charts outside of the chart itself.

[This plugin, outerLabels is exactly what I am looking for](https://github.com/robcrocombe/chartjs-plugin-outerLabels) but I am having trouble getting it to output anything.

I have been unable to find a way to get this done using Chart.js and that is what I am stuck working with for now.

I have imported the plugin both like
`import {} from 'chartjs-plugin-outerlabels';`
and also like `import 'chartjs-plugin-outerlabels';`

Here is an example of how I am setting the chart options:

```
function getPieChartOptions(chartTitle: string) {
    const options: ChartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            outerLabels: {
                fontNormalSize: 12,
                fontNormalFamily: 'sans-serif',
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                labels: {
                    usePointStyle: true,
                    font: {
                        family: 'sans-serif',
                        size: 12,
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: chartTitle,
                color: 'black',
                padding: 5,
                font: {
                    size: 16,
                    family: 'sans-serif',
                }
            },
            datalabels: {
                color: 'white',
                formatter: commas.format,
            }
        },
    };
    return options;
}
```

Here is an example of a doughnut chart within the project itself:

[image]

If anybody can help getting this plugin to work, or has another solution to this problem it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, would like to clarify that are you using Angular-directive chart.js [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#PieChart) or just pure chart.js?

Comment: And which chart.js version you used?

Comment: @YongShun I am using Chart.js 4.1.2 and it is just pure chart.js

Answer (score 0):

This works for me without the `datalabels` field (as it requires installing chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js library).

So basically the `ChartOptions` setting is similar to the one you provided.

```js
import 'chartjs-plugin-outerlabels';

getPieChartOptions(chartTitle: string) {
  const options: ChartOptions<'doughnut'> = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      outerLabels: {
        fontNormalSize: 12,
        fontNormalFamily: 'sans-serif',
      },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          font: {
            family: 'sans-serif',
            size: 12,
          },
        },
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: chartTitle,
        color: 'black',
        padding: 5,
        font: {
          size: 16,
          family: 'sans-serif',
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },
  };
  return options;
}
```

And this is how to render the chart to the canvas element.

```js
@ViewChild('MyChart', { static: true }) chart: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const ctx = this.chart.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
  new Chart<'doughnut'>(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: [['Download', 'Sales'], ['In', 'Store', 'Sales'], 'Mail Sales'],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [300, 500, 100],
        },
      ],
    },
    options: this.getPieChartOptions('doughnut'),
  } as ChartConfiguration<'doughnut'>).draw;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymv6i7?file=src/main.ts)